# Font Appears Jagged and Anti-aliasing is More Lavender Instead of Gray

Tags: css, fonts, antialiasing, typography

I'm working on a project where I'd like to match the look of the typography used on the Microsoft Teams "Client". I've matched the font (Segoe UI) and all relevant CSS styles such as font size, weight, color, background-color, etc., and yet the text on my site still appears more jagged and grainy. I'm using the same browser and monitor to compare so I know the problem is not differences in hardware.

The anti-aliasing on the Teams site appears smoother. Some screenshotting and close inspection reveal that the anti-aliasing on the Teams site is more gray in color and on my site it's more purplish in color. Everything else matches though. (See my example images below.)

I've already tried using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` and that makes no difference.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

[image: not smooth]
[image: this is smooth]

Comment: Then I have some bad news: Segoe UI may not be used as a webfont by you. In fact, you can't even buy it for that purpose, MS will not sell it to you. It comes with Windows, but that doesn't make it a free font: you may _not_ copy or redistribute it in any way, shape, or form. Of course, if you use it by relying on the system, loading it by name, and your site is only ever intended for internal use with Windows machines, then there's no problem (other than the fact that any internal machine that isn't Windows will look completely different)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well, that's some lovely news. :(

Comment: It does, however, sort of fail to answer the real question and I'm guessing we may have the same issue with the next font that we choose.

Comment: It 100% fails to answer the question, but on the flip side, if you use a proper webfont that was designed and licensed as webfont while having been made by a proper font foundry, the odds that things look the same, or at least good, in all browsers go up quite a bit.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It looks like the real issue here has to do with how we are/were loading the font. Using FontFace declarations to map different font weights to different file instances of that font was the solution. In the end we did choose to go with Noto Sans but using FontFace rules here was the correct solution. Segoe UI works properly too with those rules.

Comment: Wait, that's the _only_ way to load more than one face in a family, what were you doing before?

Comment: Yeah, it was ignorance. We were simply referencing the font in our font family rule(s) without using any font face. So I imagine the rendering of the font for different font-weights is somehow "generated" when you do it this way, thus the fault anti-aliasing.